# Why the script show the object content incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my client side code:

```
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from './Peer';
export default function TestMeeting(){
    let peerName;
    const [peerList,setPeerList]=useState({});
    const [signalSocket,setSignalSocket]=useState(io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL+"testMeeting", { transports: ['websocket'] }));

    let sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;
    if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edg")>-1){
        peerName="Edge";
    }else{
        if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome")>-1){
            peerName="Chrome";
        }else {
            if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox")>-1){
                peerName="Firefox";
            } else {
                if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari")>-1){
                    peerName="Safari";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        signalSocket.on("greeting",greeting=>{
            let peer=new Peer(greeting.from,greeting.socketId);        
            let temp={...peerList};
            temp[greeting.socketId]=peer;
            setPeerList(temp);
        })
        signalSocket.on("newPeerAdded",(remotePeer)=>{
            let peer=new Peer(remotePeer.from,remotePeer.socketId);
            peerList[remotePeer.socketId]=peer;
            let temp={...peerList};
            temp[remotePeer.socketId]=peer;
            setPeerList(temp);
            signalSocket.emit("sayHi",{socketId:remotePeer.socketId,"peerName":peerName});
        });    
    },[signalSocket,peerList,peerName])
    let connect=()=>{
        signalSocket.emit("newPeer",peerName);
    }
    console.log(peerList);
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={connect}>Connect</button>
            <div>
            {
                Object.keys(peerList).map((key,index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        {peerList[key].peerName()}
                    </div>
                ))
            }  
            </div>
        </div>
    );    
}
class Peer {
    constructor(remotePeerName,remoteSocketId) {
        let peerName=remotePeerName;
        let socketId=remoteSocketId;

        this.peerName=()=>{return peerName}
        this.socketId=()=>{return socketId}
    }
}
export default Peer;
```

Here is my server side code:

```
class TestMeeting{
    constructor(socket){
        console.log("TestMeeting:Connection established");
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log("TestSimplePeer:Disconnected");
        });
        socket.on("newPeer",(peerName)=>{
            console.log("TestMeeting:newPeer event received.")
            socket.broadcast.emit("newPeerAdded", {from:peerName,socketId:socket.id});
        });
        socket.on("sayHi",(sayHi)=>{
            console.log("sayHi event received.");
            socket.to(sayHi.socketId).emit("greeting",{from:sayHi.peerName,socketId:socket.id});
        });
    }
}
module.exports=TestMeeting;
```

**How it works**

When user click on the "connect" button, it would send "newPeer" event to other peers via server.
The other peers would response the "sayHi" event with the socket id to sender via server.

**Test case**

I opened 3 browsers to test these codes, so when I click on the "connect" button, I expect the browser console should show the following:

```
Object { e_VLiK2A2ZrSS6uqAABn: {…} }                             TestMeeting.js:45
Object { e_VLiK2A2ZrSS6uqAABn: {…}, wjsYo70xzMWwkebkAABr: {…} }  TestMeeting.js:45
```

However, the browser console show the following:

```
Object { e_VLiK2A2ZrSS6uqAABn: {…} }                             TestMeeting.js:45
Object { wjsYo70xzMWwkebkAABr: {…} }                             TestMeeting.js:45
Object { e_VLiK2A2ZrSS6uqAABn: {…}, wjsYo70xzMWwkebkAABr: {…} }  TestMeeting.js:45
```

Would you tell me what's happening? And how to fix it?

Comment: You sure you want to re-use the `newPeer` event for both sending and receiving?

Comment: If yes, what will happen?

Comment: Try separating them and see if that fits better with your expectations. Emit "newPeer" from the client when connecting but have the server emit "newPeerAdded" (or something like that) and have your clients listen for that event

Comment: I changed the code, unfortunately, it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

After several tried, I made it work:

Client side code:

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
export default function TestMeeting() {
    let peerName;
    let sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;
    if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edg") > -1) {
        peerName = "Edge";
    } else {
        if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
            peerName = "Chrome";
        } else {
            if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
                peerName = "Firefox";
            } else {
                if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
                    peerName = "Safari";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    let socket=io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL + "testMeeting", {
        transports: ["websocket"],
    })
    const initialState = { 
        peerList:{},
        socket:socket
    };
    let reducer=(state,action)=>{
        let result=null;
        switch (action.type){
            case "addPeer":
                let temp={...state.peerList};
                //console.log(state.peerList);
                temp[action.peer.socketId]=action.peer;
                result=result={...state,peerList:temp}
                break;
            case "initialPeerList":
                result={...state,peerList:action.peerList}
                break;
            case "removePeer":
                let temp1={...state.peerList};
                delete temp1[action.socketId]
                result=result={...state,peerList:temp1}
                break;
            default:
                result=state;
                break
        }
        return result;
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit("hi", peerName, (response) => {
            console.log("=======================hi===============");
            dispatch({type:"initialPeerList",peerList:response.peerList})
        });
        socket.on("newPeer", (peer) => {
        dispatch({type:"addPeer",peer:peer})
        });
        socket.on("removePeer",(socketId)=>{
            dispatch({type:"removePeer",socketId:socketId})
        });  
    },[]);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    console.log(state);
    return(
        <>
        {Object.keys(state.peerList).map((key, index) => (
            <div key={index}>{state.peerList[key].name}</div>
        ))}        
        </>
    )
}
```

Server side code:

```
class TestMeeting{
    constructor(){
        let peerList={};
        this.addPeer=(socket)=>{
            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                let peer=peerList[socket.id];
                console.log("TestSimplePeer:Disconnected");
                if (peer){
                    console.log(peer.name+" leave the meeting.");
                }
                delete peerList[socket.id];
                console.log("==================peer list===============");
                console.log(peerList);
                socket.broadcast.emit("removePeer",socket.id);
            });
            socket.on("hi",(peerName,calllBack)=>{
                peerList[socket.id]={name:peerName,socketId:socket.id};
                console.log("Received say hi from "+peerName+".");
                socket.broadcast.emit("newPeer",peerList[socket.id]);
                console.log("Broadcast newPeer ("+peerName+") to other peer.");
                calllBack({"peerList":peerList})
            })
        }
    }
}
module.exports=TestMeeting;
```